# Call a function each time an element with a class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of divs with class `preview`. Whenever the content of any div with this class changes, I need to call a function on the div whose content has changed. Currently, I javascript looks like:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('change', function(){
            var math = document.getElementsByClassName("markdownx-preview");

            console.log("element found");

            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);
        });

    </script>
```

I don't know if this approach is correct and efficient but I can easily see that it works on entire DOM and not a group of class divs. Also, to achieve result, I need to click outside the textarea which changes which is responsible for changing content insider `preview` divs.

I am new to javascript/jquery world, any hint/help to achieve the desired output will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should add ```id``` to such element apart from ```class```. Will help in making change to specific ```div```

Comment: how will the contents of div changes? can you share relevant markup?

Comment: @SandeshGupta How would it help to change from class to ID when he has Multiple elements that this should happen on?

Comment: You can look into `DOMMutator` but its expensive.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Since the person wants to call on function whose content has changed, it will be easier to alter a div with a specific id.

Comment: @SandeshGupta Problem is still that he has multiple elements that he want the trigger on. There is no problem in using class for this.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Exactly, I insisted him to use ```ID``` apart from ```class``` and not instead of ```class```. Combination of both would be an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the selector in the second argument of `$(document).on()` as `.preview` which will add a `change` listener on the `div` with class `preview`. Below is the example, write anything in the text box and then click outside the text box to remove the focus and let the script know that change has happened inside the `div`

```js
$(document).on('change', '.preview', function(){
  console.log("element found");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='preview'>
 <input type='text' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting `document`, not the individual elements that are changing.

You need to change your selector to:

```js
jQuery('.markdownx-preview').on('change', function() {
  var math = jQuery(this);

  console.log("element found");
  console.log(math.val());

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, math]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea class="markdownx-preview"></textarea>
  <textarea class="markdownx-preview"></textarea>
  <textarea class="markdownx-preview"></textarea>
</div>
```

The `change` event will fire when you LEAVE the textarea. If you want it to fire on every keypress, change the event from `change` to `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe use soemthing like this:

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "mydiv", function() { 
  //magic happens here
});
```

Change `mydiv` to yours.